# jQuery STOP buttons from appearing if input is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very new to jQuery and have been working out some kinks on a school project list app. Ive been searching for a way to make the input NOT submit if the input is blank. I've found a few ways to stop it from going, and pop up an alert message and such. But, I have 2 buttons appear when the form is submitted that show up even after trying to prevent it with alert pop ups. When I've tried making the buttons stop appearing when input is blank, I end up getting spammed with alert messages, and the buttons still show up, and the whole page gets screwy...

So my question is how can I apply an alert message, or just prevent the form from being submitted entirely AND prevent the buttons from appaearing if the input is blank.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').css('opacity', '0').fadeTo(1500, 1, 'swing');



});

$('button.submit').click(function() {
  var new_task = $('input').val() + " x" + $('input + input').val();
  var $deleteButton = $('<button />').addClass('remove').text('');
  var $li = $('<li />').text(new_task);
  var $quantityButton = $('<input type="checkbox" />');



  $('#list').append($li);
  $quantityButton.appendTo($li);
  $deleteButton.appendTo($li);
  $("form").trigger("reset");

  $('#form').click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      alert('Input can not be left blank');
    }
  });


  return false;
});



$('#list').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  console.log($(this));
});


$('#list').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  var $li = $(this).parent();

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $li.css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
  } else {
    $li.css('textDecoration', 'none');
    return false;
  }



});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Shopping list</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Old+Standard+TT:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body id="background">

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Shopping List</h2>
    <h3> </h3>
    <div class="form-list">
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="new-text" placeholder="Add item to list" />
        <input type="number" id="quantity" />
        <button class="submit"></button>


      </form>

      <ul id="list">

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">

  </div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The over all look for my project is this, if it helps.
[Mockup 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WrgP.jpg)

Thanks for all your help. I've very new to coding and I appreciate all the help and your patience!

-Thomas

Comment: You shouldn't link to code pages, but include the code here with the code snippet tool.

Comment: Sorry about that! I've uploaded the snippets. Thanks for informing me about that feature. :)

Comment: You use `#form`, but you don't have any element with the id 'form'.

Answer (score 0):

See below for validating for blank inputs. It will give alert when anyone of the inputs are blank. Modify fields as per your requirement

```js
$('button.submit').on('click', function(){  
  var blankFlag = false;
  $('input').each(function(){
    if(!jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val()).length){
      blankFlag = true;
    }
   });
    if(blankFlag){
      alert('blank');
      return false;
    }
    return true; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stop submits to submit your page.then use

```
e.preventDefault();
```

this will stop page from submitting.and use it in the submit button click.

if you want to hide the button till the textbox is empty.

```
$("#myTextBox").change(function(){
if($(this).val().length>0){$("#myButton").show()}
else{$("#myButton").hide()}
});
```

and keep the button hidden from the initial stage.hope this will work